# MeshPhongMaterial generates to much reflections

Tags: three.js, autodesk-forge

I am trying to create my own materials in Forge, which has a THREE.js engine in the bottom.

The material that I am trying to add is a MeshPhongMaterial, and I use that to be able to add a bump map to it. In the pictures below, it is all the horisontal lines on the panels.

When I make small rotations in the model, like shown in the two images, the color of choice quickly gets much darker, which I dont want. The top image is what I want to keep, and the bottom one is what happens when I am rotating in the model.

I am not an expert in this, so I would be happy if someone has some tricks to try out.

My code looks like this:

```
textureLoader.load(textureUrl, (texture) => {

                texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
                texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                    bumpScale: 0.3,
                    color: new THREE.Color (color.r / 255, color.g / 255, color.b / 255),
                    reflectivity: 0.0,
                    shading: 2,
                    side: 2,
                    shininess: 1,
                    specular: new THREE.Color(color.r / 255, color.g / 255, color.b / 255),
                });

                material.bumpMap = texture;

                material.disableEnvMap = false;

                materials.addMaterial(materialHash, material, true);
            });
```

[image: Light]

[image: Dark]

Answer (score 0):

Try MeshLambert material instead of Phong...

https://gist.github.com/wallabyway/4503609e84a2b612b27138abba8aa3b7

UPDATE:
You can override the material (that comes from SVF)...

something like this:

```
viewer = NOP_VIEWER;

const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                side: THREE.DoubleSide,
                color: new THREE.Color(1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                reflectivity: 0.0,
                shininess: 0
            });
material.disableEnvMap = false;
viewer.impl.matman().addMaterial('test', material, true);

const tree = viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
const frags = viewer.model.getFragmentList();
tree.enumNodeFragments(tree.getRootId(), function (fragid) { frags.setMaterial(fragid, material); }, true);
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. One question, when I am running this Revit-model through the model derivative api to get the svf, the derivative is generating MeshPhong materials, and they don't these amount of reflections. I am finding it hard to cope, that the properties regarding reflections doesn't have any affect in the viewer, when I am setting it up myself. Can you answer?

Comment: Ok Michael, I get that. But that means that I should be dissatisfied with the materials coming from the derivative service, and find it much better to use my own. My case is the other way around. I think that the materials coming from the derivative seems better than the ones I use myself, since they aren't reflecting that much. Si I cannot understand how to create these materials myself via three.js. I have played around with many properties, but the mighty reflections are there all the time. Some property that I have missed. ?

Comment: Please see new blog post: https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/fix-material-reflections-forge-viewer